# How to setup solr 8.11 replication slave?

Tags: solr

I try to setup a solr master/slave replication. But I've some issues to understand how I setup the slave solr. In each documentation or "How to do" there are only described the different solrconfig.xml for slave but not how I should setup them.

Should I create on the slave also a core too? Because when I do it, the slave solr didn't recognized that he should be a slave. When I call `/replication?command=details` on slave, the output are

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1},
  "status":"OK",
  "details":{
    "indexSize":"69 bytes",
    "indexPath":"/var/solr/data/vdiParts/data/index/",
    "commits":[[
        "indexVersion",0,
        "generation",1,
        "filelist",["segments_1"]]],
    "isMaster":"true",
    "isSlave":"false",
    "indexVersion":0,
    "generation":1,
    "master":{
      "replicateAfter":["commit"],
      "replicationEnabled":"true"}}}
```

So he thinks he is a master. In slave solrconfig.xml I create the correct requestHandler

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">
        <lst name="follower">
            <str name="leaderUrl">http://[host]:8983/solr/[core]/replication</str>
            <str name="pollInterval">00:00:20</str>
            <str name="httpConnTimeout">5000</str>
            <str name="httpReadTimeout">10000</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>
```

Thx!

Comment: Have you added this as the actual `solrconfig.xml` on the follower, and not as `solrconfig-follower.xml` or a different name?

Comment: Yes, I renamed it into correct `solrconfig.xml`

Answer (score 0):

> Should I create on the slave also a core too? Because when I do it, the slave solr didn't recognized that he should be a slave.

Yes, you need to create the second core and after you have done that, update its `solrconfig.xml` to indicate that where is the master Solr.

`solrconfig.xml` in the master core will have a section like this:

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">
  <lst name="master">
    <str name="replicateAfter">optimize</str>
    <str name="backupAfter">optimize</str>
    <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,stopwords.txt</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

whereas the `solrconfig.xml` in the slave will have a section that looks more or less like this:

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">
  <lst name="slave">
    <str name="masterUrl">http://localhost:8983/solr/bibdata/replication</str>
    <str name="pollInterval">00:00:20</str>
    <str name="compression">internal</str>
    <str name="httpConnTimeout">5000</str>
    <str name="httpReadTimeout">10000</str>
    <str name="httpBasicAuthUser">username</str>
    <str name="httpBasicAuthPassword">password</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

More details https://github.com/hectorcorrea/solr-for-newbies/blob/code4lib_2018/tutorial.md#solr-replication